# Remove dictionary from array where value is empty string (Using Higher Order Functions)

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, higher-order-functions

I have a Array of dictionary

```
    var details:[[String:String]] = [["name":"a","age":"1"],["name":"b","age":"2"],["name":"c","age":""]]
    print(details)//[["name": "a", "age": "1"], ["name": "b", "age": "2"], ["name": "c", "age": ""]]
```

Now I want to remove dictionary from array where value is empty string. I've achieved this with a nested for loop.

```
    for (index,detail) in details.enumerated()
    {
       for (key, value) in detail
       {
        if value == ""
        {
            details.remove(at: index)
        }
       }
    }
    print(details)//[["name": "a", "age": "1"], ["name": "b", "age": "2"]]
```

How can I achieve this with Higher Order Functions(Map, filter, reduce and flatMap)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your `for` loop, it seems you want to remove dictionaries from `details` if any key-value pair therein contains an empty `String`, `""`, as a value. For this, you could e.g. apply `filter` on `details`, and as a predicate to the `filter`, check the `values` property of each dictionary for the non-existance of `""` (/non-existance of an empty `String`). E.g.

```
var details: [[String: String]] = [
    ["name": "a", "age": "1"],
    ["name": "b", "age": "2"],
    ["name": "c", "age": ""]
]

let filteredDetails = details.filter { !$0.values.contains("") }
print(filteredDetails)
/* [["name": "a", "age": "1"], 
     "name": "b", "age": "2"]] */
```

or,

```
let filteredDetails = details
    .filter { !$0.values.contains(where: { $0.isEmpty }) }
```

---

On another note: seeing you use an array of dictionaries with a few seemingly "static" keys, I would advice you to consider using a more appropriate data structure, e.g. a custom `Struct`. E.g.:

```
struct Detail {
    let name: String
    let age: String
}

var details: [Detail] = [
    Detail(name: "a", age: "1"),
    Detail(name: "b", age: "2"),
    Detail(name: "c", age: "")
]

let filteredDetails = details.filter { !$0.name.isEmpty && !$0.age.isEmpty }
print(filteredDetails)
/* [Detail(name: "a", age: "1"),
    Detail(name: "b", age: "2")] */
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use  the filter method of array as below.

```
let arrFilteredDetails = details.filter { ($0["name"] != "" || $0["age"] != "")}
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for that it was typo in hurry. Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: I think the logic you're looking for is `let arrFilteredDetails = details.filter { !($0["name"] == "" || $0["age"] == "") }`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
let filtered = details.filter { !$0.values.contains { $0.isEmpty }}
```

This is also independent from the internal dictionary structure (like name of the keys)